# pgrouting error when trying to dump data into database

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

I was just following this tutorial **[HERE](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/advanced.html)**, its about, pgrouting, When I run the following command:

```
psql -U user -d postgres -f ~/Desktop/pgrouting-workshop/data/sampledata_routing.sql
```

I get an error saying the following:

```
/var/lib/postgresql/Desktop/pgrouting-workshop/data/sampledata_routing.sql: No such file or directory
```

On my desktop I do have a folder `pgrouting-workshop`, which does contain the folder `data` and the `sql` dump file.

So why am I getting this error?

Comment: x-posted as http://askubuntu.com/q/671056/75715

Comment: Because your `Desktop` isn't in the `postgres` user's home directory, located at `/var/lib/postgresql`, but is instead located at `/home/myusername/Desktop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `Desktop` isn't in the `postgres` user's home directory, located at `/var/lib/postgresql`, but is instead located at `/home/myusername/Desktop`?

Presumably the `psql` command you're running is under a `sudo -u postgres -i` shell, so `~/` means the `postgres` user's home directory.

Use `~myusername/Desktop/blahblah`. Note that the `postgres` user may not have permission to access it; you can `chmod go+x ~ ~/Desktop` (run as your user, not `postgres`) to change that.